# My FBMP app can't load suddenly

Tags: facebook, fbml

7 or 8 hours ago, my facebook FBML application can't load, it doesn't show any error, it can be a facebook problem? I didn't modify any file for the application crash.

Thanks!

Mikel.

Comment: Are you using Legacy fb_sig_xxx based authentication or OAuth 2.0? Also are you using Legacy REST API or Graph API?

Comment: No, I'm using the FBML method like always. require_once 'facebook.php';
$appapikey = 'xxx';
$appsecret = 'xxx';
$facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret);
$user_id = $facebook->require_login();
?>
<fb:if-user-has-added-app> <fb:dashboard>  more code....

Answer (score 1):

It can be a related issue https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/182705755149358?browse=search_4ec3beea8af119f67451579.

By the way you should have a look on their roadmap https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap they'll deprecate FBML on January 1, 2012.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Guess `require_login()` is a part of old PHP SDK which uses legacy auth
From yesterday FB has dropped `fb_sig_xxxx` params, which are used for legacy auth.
We are also facing the same issue with Java client.
It is the time to upgrade to oAuth.
Migrating to PHP SDK 3.0 should help.